# alert message when i select wrong in drop down list

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have two drop down list one lets assume ddl1 and ddl2. Both dropdown list bind hard coded in aspx page i want if i select ddl2 value if i selected some value suppose its not related to ddl1 value then show me alert message  Please help me

My codes

```
public void BindSub()
        {
            Cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_P_BindSub", Con.OpenConnection());
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            ddlSBU.DataSource = dt;
            ddlSBU.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlSBU.DataTextField = "SBU_Name";
            ddlSBU.DataBind();

            ddlSBU.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));
        }

        protected void ddlSBU_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_P_BindDepartment", Con.OpenConnection());
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SBU_ID", ddlSBU.SelectedValue);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            ddlDepartment.DataSource = dt;
            ddlDepartment.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlDepartment.DataTextField = "Department_Name";
            ddlDepartment.DataBind();
            ddlDepartment.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));
        }





<script >
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#ddlemployeetype").change(function () {
               value1 = document.getelementbytext("ddlemployeetype").value;
               value2 = document.getelementbytext("ddlrole").value;


              case "Employee":
                   document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0] = new Option("select", "");
                   document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1] = new Option("Cordinator", "Cordinator");
                   document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2] = new Option("Filecer", "Filecer");

                   break;

               case "Contractor":
                   document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0] = new Option("select", "");
                   document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1] = new Option("Leader", "Leader");
                   document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2] = new Option("Member", "Member");
                   break;
                   break;

           return true;

               if (value1 != value2) {
                   alert("not related value");
               }

           });
       });



</script>
```

my ddl1 values are Contractor and employee and ddl2 values are cordinator, leader, facilator, leader2, member. 
Condition : facilator and cordinator belongs to employee if i selected somthing other then show me message its wrong selection

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to edit the display of ddl2 based on the selection in ddl1? That way only valid selections would be available.

Comment: yes but, in my case dropdown values are hard coded otherwise on basis of id we can select dependency value but don't know in hard coded

Comment: Hard coding should be avoided as much as possible. If you provide your users with invalid selections and slap their hand every time they make a wrong selection, they will get frustrated very quickly. Not a very good UX.

Comment: right ........... is it possible in this case??????

Comment: With your jQuery above, what haapens that shouldn't? What doesn't happen that should? What error messages are you getting (you should get at least one as you switch statement is broken)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddl1").change(function () {
        value1 = document.getElementById("ddl1").value;
        value2 = document.getElementById("ddl2").value;

        // here write your business logic
        if (value1 != value2) {
            alert("not related value");
        }

    });
});
```